# why isn't my apple podcast cover art updating

Tags: rss, itunes, podcast

my podcast https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/new-church-eco-presbyterian/id638268733?mt=2 hasn't updated my cover art in over 2 weeks.  Anybody know how often they update the art.  Here's a snipit of my rss code:

```
<itunes:subtitle>Listen to the Sermons of our Pastors and Guests</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:summary>Evergreen Church, GA- Listen to the Sermons of our Pastors and      Guests</itunes:summary>
<itunes:image href="http://www.evergreenchurchga.org/content/images/evergreen_images/kerned_logo_itunes.jpg" />
<itunes:category text="Religion &amp; Spirituality">
        <itunes:category text="Christianity"/>
    </itunes:category>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the file name for the image and update your RSS feed to use the new file name.

From the [iTunes Podcast specification document](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#image):

> If you change your podcast’s image, also change the file’s name. iTunes may not change the image if it checks your feed and the image URL is the same. The server hosting your cover art image must allow HTTP head requests for iTS to be able to automatically update your cover art.

Hope that helps.